# How to make "watch" command process \r (carriage return) correctly?

Tags: bash, special-characters, watch, carriage-return

I am trying to use `watch` command to watch the content changes in a file.

However, the file contains a progress bar, which uses the `\r` character to overwrite on itself. **The `watch` command seem to ignore these `\r` characters.**

For example, if I create a file that contains a carriage return:

```
$ echo -e "Looooong-string \r short-string" > test.txt
```

If I `cat` the file, the contents overwrites on itself correctly:

```
$ cat test.txt 
 short-stringng
```

But if I `watch` this `cat` command, the `\r` will be ignored.

```
$ watch cat file.txt
Every 2.0s: cat test.txt                    Sun Aug 28 21:39:59 2022

Looooong-string   short-string
```

Is there any way to make `watch` process these `\r`s correctly and make the string overwrite on itself?

Comment: Looks like `watch` removes any non printable character except `\n` and `\t`. Check the source code: https://github.dev/warmchang/procps/blob/401d587d2deb78adcf62517654f955a24b2d537d/watch.c#L649

Comment: Watch is not a shell command, let alone something Linux-specific. You can retrieve and study the source code for it easily, if you're interested in changing its behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Doing

```
while :
do
    cat test.txt &
    sleep 2
    clear
done
```

works reasonably well.

Comment: yes, looping and sleeping your self is the solution, but you don't need to run the command in background with `&`

Comment: You do if the command takes, say, 1 second to run.

Comment: This is perfect. Though it clogs the terminal.. Really not sure why watch doesn't allow for this.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual I can read

```
Non-printing characters are stripped from program output.  Use cat -v as part of the command pipeline if you want to see them.
```

And if you ran `watch cat -v test.txt` the output is

```
Looooong-string ^M short-string
```

Comment: this won't work if the OP really wants the actual `\r` behavior

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here seems to just be to write your own basic version of `watch`. This is actually pretty simple.

Here's my take on @actual quak's answer. I made various changes to allow a lot more customization as well as add additional output to be more informational.

```
#! /bin/bash

# Defaults
filename=log_file.log
num_lines=20
sleep_s=30

# Parse any arguments
while getopts f:n:s: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        f) filename=${OPTARG};;
        n) num_lines=${OPTARG};;
        s) sleep_s=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done

# "watch" file
while :
do
  clear
  echo "$(cat /etc/hostname): $(date)"
  echo "Every ${sleep_s}s: tail -n $num_lines $filename &"
  echo
  tail -n $num_lines $filename &
  sleep $sleep_s
done
```

You can save this in a file called `watch_tail.sh`, run `chmod +x watch_tail.sh` against it, and run it with `./watch_tail.sh`.

An example when passing custom args:

```
./watch_tail.sh -f test.txt -n 30 -s 2
```

It is obviously not `watch` so do note that most of its options are not available. This will also actually output everything in your terminal so it can clog it up, if that is of import to you.